# How to init WKWebView with already existing bearer token

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm implementing an iOS app which authenticates to my web service and receives a token. I have embedded a `WKWebView` to my app so that I can open one specific web page in which I have javascript that tries to read the token from local storage. How can I init the `WKWebView` so that my token is accessible from the local storage?

Edit: Here is a discussion telling a way to enable local storage: [iOS WKWebView does not support local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622032/ios-wkwebview-does-not-support-local-storage) but it seems that adding an item to local storage from app code is not possible.

Comment: Please add your code and try!

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the token in header of request that would pe passed to webview, as:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://yourdomain.com") {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("auth token value", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
}
```

Comment: This adds token to the request header but I am looking for a way to insert the token to local storage of the WkWebView. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

you can add to local storage: key is AccessToken and value is the token

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script())

func script() -> WKUserScript {

 let source = "localStorage.setItem('AccessToken', '\(getAccessToken())');"

 return WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been busy with another tasks. I don't have possibility to verify this solution proposal yet but it seems to do the trick. I will update this whenever I have possibility to test it.

Answer (score -4):

I have created a viewcontroller which will create webview instance for you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

        //Kind of crazy stuff
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //General view with page, followed by link
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")! //example
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

    }
        //I do not sure, is that ui?
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    }


}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question but thanks for the effort.